# How to use bootstrap 4 in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4

I installed bootstrap 4 using npm on my laravel app. But I think bootstrap 3 working behind not bootstrap 4.
using command:

  npm install

  npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6

Did I left something to do?
Or do I need to manually import bootstrap to assets/sass/app.scss file or else?

Comment: it should be somewhere in the `public` folder. Then include it like always in html, but now somewhere in your blade

Comment: I actually don't understand you.But  assets compiling from assets directory and those js and css file importing bootstrap 3 ,thats the problem I think.

Comment: @unreleased have you updated the paths to Bootstrap in your assets? For example in your Scss https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/sass/app.scss#L9.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to manually change the link to bootstrap from `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`. You will see this line

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Replace with

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: prevoiusly tried `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss";` and got some error. Now its solved.Thank you :)

Comment: @unreleased, you may also want to load the script of bootstrap4, if you do, change`require(bootstrap-sass');` with `require('bootstrap');` in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: also ```npm install popper.js```

Answer (score 10):

Do flowing with new or empty **Laravel** project.

- remove the bootstrap entry from `package.json` and replace it with
  `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"`.
- In `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`, `comment` out the `import` of `variables`.
- Change the path of bootstrap to `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`
- In `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`, look for `require('bootsrap-sass');` and change it to `require('bootstrap');`
- Bring in the `javascript` by editing the `webpack.mix.js`.

**JavaScript**

```
mix.js([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/app.js'], 'public/js');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css/admin'); /* If you want to make admin css file. */
```

- run `$ npm install`
- Check `node_modules` folder for `bootstrap` and `jquery` is install properly. If not install then install manually.
- For bootstrap4 `$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`
- For jquery `$ npm install jquery`

If all goes well, you should be able to run `npm run dev`.

> Note: If you need `tether.js` then use `cdn` or install manually. Because `bootstrap@4` required `tether.js` for `tooltip`.

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/tip-using-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-with-laravel-54)

Comment: Editing webpack.mix.js is unnecessary since app.js requires bootstrap.js, which requires both jQuery and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment out the `@import "variables";` line from `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

The import directive is called 2 times, one in `app.scss` and then in the bootstrap.scss file from the installation directory

Answer (score 0):

1.npm install

2.npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6

3.Change the path of bootstrap in "resources/assets/sass/app.scss" to @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

4.Change $font-size-base: 14px; in variable.scss to $font-size-base:0.875 rem;

5.In resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js, look for require('bootsrap-sass'); and change it to require('bootstrap');

6. run npm install & run npm dev

bootstrap 4(check out in app.css) will be installed to your laravel 5.4 or lesser version,
since laravel 5.4 or less uses bootstrap version 3.4.1 all the default styles will change and inbuilt laravel UI will change.