# Bootstrap-4 with Laravel: missing bootstrap classes

Tags: css, node.js, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel and I tried to install Bootstrap 4 Beta into my project. At first it seamed to work, but after a short time I noticed that there where bootstrap classes missing. Especially classes which have overall classes and classes with breakpoints, like:

display classes: d-block, d-inline, d-none, ...
padding classes: p-1, pt-3, ...
margin classes: mx-2, mb-5, ...

All those classes without breakpoints are missing in the bootstrap css file. There only the classes with breakpoints like:

d-md-inline, px-lg-3, ...

I tryed to install bootstrap 4 via npm and the app.css tells me that bootstrap 4.0.0.beta3 is installed but those classes keep missing. I tryed to uninstall bootstrap via npm and reinstalled it, but the problem keeps the same. Hase anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can read this: [How to use bootstrap 4 in Laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442834/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-laravel-5-4) maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happend, but after a second reinstallation of bootstrap 4 the issue was solved.